# Hashing same string and same salt giving different hash result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hash, passwords

I am trying to use the code from [Microsoft Docs Hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to hash a password and store it in a database. Saving the hash and salt works fine.
My hashing method:

```
public Tuple<string,string> PasswordCrypting(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt:salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        Tuple<string, string> credentials = new Tuple<string, string>(hashed, Convert.ToBase64String(salt));
        return credentials;
    }
```

On user login I retrieve the salt from the database and use it to recreate the hash using the user's password input and the salt. I would use the hash I get to compare with the one stored in database.

```
public string PasswordDecrypting(string username,string password)
    {
        string salt = _userManager.GetPassSalt(username);
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: Convert.FromBase64String(salt),
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        return hashed;
    }
```

The problem is that I can never get the same hash as in the database. I debugged my code and the salt matches the one in the database and the password string is the same as when first hashing; the same algorithm is used, but the resulting hash is different from the one I should get.

Is this algorithm made so it never makes the same hash, and if so how can I recreate my hash?

Comment: The salt matches the salt in the db, but are you sure it's the same salt as the one used to create the initial hash?

Comment: With hashes, there is no "Decrypting". Instead you run the input through the *same* hash function you used for the original. Having a seperate "Decyrpt" function just makes no sense.

Comment: PasswordCrypting should take the Salt - generated for it by outside code - as parameter. Then it does not mater if it get's the salt from Random generation or the Database. And you can turn this into a simple string return value.

Comment: @JonathonChase how can I make sure to save the one used to create the hash?

Comment: The way you make _make sure to save the [salt] used to create the hash_ is you make sure you save the salt used to create the hash.  You either save it in the database as part of the user record or calculate in a way that doesn't change for a particular user.  For example, if you have an unchanging GUID associated with a user record, use it as salt.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core or is there a reason you are using `KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2` instead of [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netcore-3.0)?

Comment: @Herohtar Among other things, I've edited the question to include the [tag:asp.net-core] tag since OP links to an explicitly ASP.NET Core-specific tutorial at the beginning of their question.

Comment: @TylerH Turns out this question should be closed as a typo anyway -- see OP's comment on the answer stating that the problem was due to accidentally calling the method twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a unit test to test your code. And must draw the conclusion that you are not storing the salt properly, or you are, in some way, altering the salt before storing or after retrieving it from the database.

I wrote the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_SaltGeneration()
    {
        var password = "48F3A112-F574-4B25-B226-CE97888FCBCB";

        var firstResult = PasswordCrypting(password);

        var secondResult = PasswordDecrypting(password, firstResult.salt);

        Assert.IsTrue(firstResult.hash.Equals(secondResult));
    }

    public (string hash, string salt) PasswordCrypting(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));

        return (hashed, Convert.ToBase64String(salt));
    }

    public string PasswordDecrypting(string password, string salt )
    {
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: Convert.FromBase64String(salt),
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        return hashed;
    }
```

As you might guess. This test passes. Implying my first assertion.

Comment: Yes I made a stupid mistake, when saving hash and salt I called the method twice thus resulting in a different salt. Thank you for your time.